# Lifetime estimation from non-longitudinal data

Tags: survival

I am essentially trying to estimate some measure of the lifetime of individuals from non-longitudinal data (I don't have repeated measurements of the same individual). I measure whether an individuals is alive or dead for all individuals at a single time point, and know when each individual was born relative to the time of measurement.

To get a rough idea of what is happening, I normally will take bins of 'time since birth' from this dataset and calculate the proportion of individuals who are alive at that bin, which leads to something which looks somewhat similar to an empirical distribution function, and can eyeball around which time 50% of the individuals are dead to estimate the median lifetime, however I would like to have a more formal analysis, and was wondering if anyone had any approaches which could be applied here. I think my approach is somewhat similar to doing logistic regression where the dependent variable is whether the individual is alive or dead, and the regressor is the time since birth of the measurement, and I could estimate the time of 0.5 probability of being dead. This doesn't seem ideal though since it would be parametric, and it only seems to implicitly integrate the temporal nature of the data.

I appreciate any suggestions for this analysis!

EDIT: I forgot to describe the sampling - I am randomly sampling from a population which for the sake of simplicity can be considered roughly uniform over some interval. As an alternative sampling approach I can also sample from populations where all the individuals are born at the same time and choose different populations with different birth times. In this way, I could pool the data and essentially each of my "bins" would be from a different population.

Comment: How are you sampling individuals?

Comment: Sorry I meant to describe the sampling - I am randomly sampling from a population which for the sake of simplicity can be considered roughly uniform over some interval. As an alternative sampling approach I can also sample from populations where all the individuals are born at the same time and choose different populations with different birth times. In this way, I could pool the data and essentially each of my "bins" would be from a different population.

Comment: How do you select the representative date? Certain periods (wars, natural disasters, pandemics, economic depressions,....) versus very good years both may present a degree of bias over say averaging of various time periods.